# Laravel-5.7: All categories are not showing in header from db

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I'm trying to get all main categories in the header of site but only one category is showing, can anyone provide the solution for this?

Here is ProductsController:

**ProductsController.php**

```
public function products($url = null)
{

  $categories = Category::with('products')->where(['parent_id'=>0])->get();
  $categoryDetails = Category::where(['url' => $url])->first();

  if($categoryDetails->parent_id==0)
  {
      //if url is main category url
      $subCategories = Category::where(['parent_id'=>$categoryDetails])->get();
      $cat_ids = "";
      foreach ($subCategories as $subCat) {
          $cat_ids .= $subCat->id.",";
      }
      $productsAll = Product::whereIn('category_id',array($cat_ids))->get();
  }
  else
  {
      //if url is sub category url
      $productsAll = Product::where(['category_id' => $categoryDetails->id])
                          ->get();
  }

  return view('products.listing')
            ->with(compact('categories','categoryDetails','productsAll'));
}
```

and on the `listing.blade.php` I write this to relate it with categories:

```
{{ $categoryDetails->name }}
```

Code of Controller:

**Controller.php**

```
<?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers;

  use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
  use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
  use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
  use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
  use App\Category;

  class Controller extends BaseController
  {
   use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    public static function mainCategories(){
    $mainCategories = Category::where(['parent_id' => 0])->get();
    $mainCategories = json_decode(json_encode($mainCategories));
    /*echo "<pre>"; print_r($mainCategories); die;*/
    return $mainCategories;
    }
   }
```

The code I write in the header view:

**header.blade.php**

```html
<?php use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
  $mainCategories =  Controller::mainCategories();
?>

<!--some html-->

@foreach($mainCategories as $cat)
          <div class="dropdown-content">
               <a href="{{ asset('products/'.$cat->url) }}" style="margin-bottom: -10px;">{{ $cat->name }}</a>
          </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: `$mainCategories =  Controller::mainCategories();` should be `Category::mainCategories();`

Comment: it says:Class 'Category' not found

Comment: Change `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;` to `use App\Http\Controllers\Category;` also

Comment: sory it says: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Category' not found

Comment: Where is your `Category` class living? You can check it from `MyController.php`. Find that and correct the path that's it.

Comment: sory mycontroller is not any controller, m using the default Controller.php for it, i also updated it in question, and it is mentioned above

Comment: you're using `Category` class in `ProductsController.php` and `Controller` so check `Category` class in there please. It will be at the top of the file. Copy the path and use it in `header.blade.php`

Comment: If you can't find it please share `ProductsController` or `Controller` top code I will help you.

Comment: <?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use App\Category;
class Controller extends BaseController
{use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
public static function mainCategories(){
$mainCategories = Category::where(['parent_id' => 0])->get();
$mainCategories = json_decode(json_encode($mainCategories)); return $mainCategories;}}

Comment: this is the complete Controller.php

Comment: @Iftikharuddin i hv updated the question and fill code of Comtroller.php is mentioned now, and also ProductsController

Comment: @Azid check my updated answer please :) Just `use App\Category;`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
<?php use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
  $mainCategories =  Controller::mainCategories();
?>
```

to

```
<?php 
  use App\Controller;
  $mainCategories =  Controller::mainCategories();
?>
```

or more directly:

```
<?php 
   $mainCategories =  App\Controller::mainCategories();
?>
```

in `header.blade.php`

Comment: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Category' not found

Comment: Call to undefined method App\Category::mainCategories()

Comment: same error, i think the problem is in products controller

Comment: @azibdhaken can you share `Category` Model?

Comment: <?php

   namespace App;

   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

   class Category extends Model
  {
     public function products(){
     return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
  }

}

Comment: Ah so your `mainCategories` func is in `Controller`. Try the updated answer please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use View data for this (https://laravel.com/docs/master/views#passing-data-to-views) :

In your `App/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` file :

```
public function boot()
{
    View::share('mainCategories', Category::where(['parent_id' => 0])->get());
}
```

And just use :

```
@foreach($mainCategories as $cat)
  // .... your code
@endforeach
```

In your template files.